# How to tell if the user is not in a voice channel

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I am trying to make the bot send an error message if the user is not in a voice channel. This is what I've tried so far and it doesn't work.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        try:
            if voice and voice.is_connected():
                await voice.move_to(channel)
                await ctx.send(f'Moved to {channel}')
            else:
                voice = await channel.connect()
                await ctx.send(f'Connected to {channel}')
        except:
            await ctx.send('You are not in a voice channel.')
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Are you getting any errors? Have you printed any of the variables to see what they contained? My best guess is that ``voice`` is actually ``None`` when they aren't in a channel, so you can't request it's ``channel`` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Member.voice` to check if they are connected to a voice channel.

Below is the revised code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        return await ctx.send('You are not in a voice channel.')
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = ctx.voice_client
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
        await ctx.send(f'Moved to {channel}')
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f'Connected to {channel}')
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. @Poojan